# Test class Failed: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex

My test class is failing and I can't figure out why. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

This is the error message:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
>
> Stack Trace Class.GenerateJobOfferController.: line 6, column 1
>                      Class.GenerateJobOfferController_Tests.myUnitTest: line 15, column 1

This is the test class as a whole:

```
@isTest
private class GenerateJobOfferController_Tests {

static Account objAccount;   
static Contact objContact;
static Job_Order__c objJobOrder;
static Candidate__c objCandidate;
static Candidate_Applications__c objApplication;


static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
    // TO DO: implement unit test
     LoadData();
    ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(objApplication);
    GenerateJobOfferController objGenerateJobOfferController = new GenerateJobOfferController(stdController);

}

static void LoadData(){
    createAccount();
    createContact();
    createJobOrder();
    createCandidate();
    createApplication();

}

static void createAccount(){
    objAccount = new Account();
    objAccount.Name = 'Test Account';

    insert objAccount;

    //assert..........
    Account TempAccount = new Account();
    TempAccount = [select id from Account where id =:objAccount.id];
    system.assertEquals(TempAccount.id == objAccount.id, true);
}
static void createContact(){
    objContact = new Contact();
    objContact.LastName = 'Test Contact';
    objContact.email = 'benX585@gmail.com';
    objContact.AccountId = objAccount.id;

    insert objContact;

    //assert..........
    Contact TempContact = new Contact();
    TempContact = [select id from Contact where id =:objContact.id];
    system.assertEquals(TempContact.id == objContact.id, true);
}

static void createJobOrder(){
    objJobOrder = new Job_Order__c();
    objJobOrder.Job_Title__c = 'Test Title';
    objJobOrder.Start_Date__c = date.today();
    objJobOrder.End_Date__c = date.today();
    objJobOrder.Status__c = 'Hiring';
    objJobOrder.Contact_Client__c = objContact.id;
    objJobOrder.Salary_Range__c = '123-123';
    objJobOrder.Experience_level_desired__c = 'Student';

    insert objJobOrder;

    //assert..........
    Job_Order__c TempJobOrder = new Job_Order__c();
    TempJobOrder = [select id from Job_Order__c where id =:objJobOrder.id];
    system.assertEquals(TempJobOrder.id == objJobOrder.id, true);
}
static void createCandidate(){
    objCandidate = new Candidate__c();
    objCandidate.Last_Name__c = 'Test Candidate';

    insert objCandidate;

    //assert..........
    Candidate__c TempCandidate = new Candidate__c();
    TempCandidate = [select id from Candidate__c where id =:objCandidate.id];
    system.assertEquals(TempCandidate.id == objCandidate.id, true);
}

static void createApplication(){
    objApplication = new Candidate_Applications__c();
    objApplication.Candidate_Status__c = 'New';
    objApplication.Job_Order__c = objJobOrder.id;
    objApplication.Candidate__c = objCandidate.id;

    insert objApplication;

    //assert..........
    Candidate_Applications__c TempApplication = new Candidate_Applications__c();
    TempApplication = [select id from Candidate_Applications__c where id =:objApplication.id];
    system.assertEquals(TempApplication.id == objApplication.id, true);
}    

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the `GenerateJobOfferController` constructor as well?

Answer (score 3):

Your failure is in the constructor of GenerateJobOfferController.

A query (on line 6) is not finding any records and you are assigning it directly to a single sObject.  This causes salesforce to throw an exception.

Without seeing the code for that class its hard to give more specific details.  Are you using a page parameter in a query?

```
acc = [SELECT Id, ... FROM Account WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
```

If so, you need to set it up in your test:

```
static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
    // TO DO: implement unit test
    LoadData();

  //set up query param        
   Test.setCurrentPageReference(new PageReference('Page.myPage'));
    System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('id', objAccount.Id);

    ApexPages.StandardController stdController = new ApexPages.StandardController(objApplication);
    GenerateJobOfferController objGenerateJobOfferController = new GenerateJobOfferController(stdController);

}
```